# I keep getting parenthesis error in SQL Oracle when introducing a foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been searching and playing around with the code trying to figure out why its giving me parenthesis error when I followed the format of Oracle referencing in other tables

```
Create table TourOperator (TOID int PRIMARY KEY, Cname varchar (20), phone long int);

Create table Airline(Aname varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY, Website varchar(255), Phone int(10), TOID int, FOREIGN KEY(TOID) REFERENCES TourOperator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues in your SQL, according to the Oracle syntax:

- The type `INT` cannot be qualified with a size.
- The type `VARCHAR` technically does exist in Oracle, but is not recommended; use `VARCHAR2` instead.
- The syntax of the foreign key clause is wrong.
- Avoid the type `LONG`; it's a legacy type that you shouldn't use for new databases. I changed the `phone` column to `VARCHAR2`.

The SQL can run as:

```
Create table TourOperator (
  TOID int PRIMARY KEY, 
  Cname varchar2(20), 
  phone varchar2(20)
);

Create table Airline(
  Aname varchar2(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
  Website varchar2(255), 
  Phone int, 
  TOID int REFERENCES TourOperator (TOID)
);
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba50c7da47039ead633675898519ea36).

Comment: thanks a lot, was juts wondering what the difference between varchar1 and 2 ?

Comment: @Wietlol explained in the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the target column of the foreign key in the TourOperator table. Try this:

```
Create table TourOperator 
(TOID int PRIMARY KEY,
 Cname varchar2(20),
 phone long int
);

Create table Airline 
(Aname varchar2(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
 Website varchar2(255), 
 Phone int,
 TOID int,
 FOREIGN KEY(TOID) REFERENCES TourOperator(TOID)
);
```

For more examples, see here: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-foreign-key/